# #Repr[A] in Akka Stream source type

Tags: scala, stream, akka

I have the following piece of code that creates a sources that outputs `MarketFactors`. However, I would like to be able to switch type of random generator or what the `toMarketFactors` function does.

However, since all the transformations on the initial source are in the type I cannot transform it to a generic type in the trait the class implements (`Option[Source[MarketFactors, NotUsed]]`), what do I need to do?

I'm attaching the `Sink` and materializing later on, is this a bad practice?

```
override def factors: Option[Source[CorrelatedRandomVectorGenerator, NotUsed]#Repr[MarketFactors]] = {
    val source = for { g <- generator } yield Source.repeat(g)

    val marketFactors = Flow[CorrelatedRandomVectorGenerator].map(toMarketFactors)

    source.map(_.via(marketFactors))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use type parameter on `factors` method.

```
case class CorrelatedRandomVectorGenerator()
case class MarketFactors1()
case class MarketFactors2()

def factors[T](transformation: CorrelatedRandomVectorGenerator => T): Option[Source[T, NotUsed]] = {
  val generator = Option.empty[CorrelatedRandomVectorGenerator]
  val source = for { g <- generator } yield Source.repeat(g)

  val marketFactors = Flow[CorrelatedRandomVectorGenerator].map(transformation)
  source.map(_.via(marketFactors))
}

val toMarketFactors1: CorrelatedRandomVectorGenerator => MarketFactors1 = ???
val toMarketFactors2: CorrelatedRandomVectorGenerator => MarketFactors2 = ???

val source1: Option[Source[MarketFactors1, NotUsed]] = factors(toMarketFactors1)
val source2: Option[Source[MarketFactors2, NotUsed]] = factors(toMarketFactors2)
```